# Help finding maximum power on R4 using Thévenin

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws, thevenin, norton

I'm trying to solve the question using Thévenin but I'm getting wrong answers.

Question:

> Find The Maximum Power on \$R_4\$
> [image]

---

**My Try:**

I Started with Finding \$R_{th}\$ by disconnecting \$R_4\$ :

Then using Node Voltage Analysis:
[image]

---

**Some Observations:**

\$\begin{aligned}V_{s}=V_{A}-V_{B} \Longrightarrow V_{A}=15+V_{B}\\
I_{\Delta }=\dfrac{V_{A}-V_{B}}{R_{3}}=\dfrac{15}{600}=\dfrac{1}{40} [A] \end{aligned} \$

---

**Node Equations for Super-Node:**

$$ \begin{gathered}\left( 1\right)\dfrac{V_{A}-V_{s1}}{300}+\dfrac{V_{A}}{330}+I_{\Delta }=-10i_{\Delta}+\dfrac{V_{B}}{200}-i\Delta \\
\Rightarrow V_{A}\cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{300}+\dfrac{1}{330}\right) =V_{B}\cdot \left( \dfrac{1}{200}\right) -12 \cdot \dfrac{1}{40}+\dfrac{1}{30}\\
V_{B}\cdot \left( \dfrac{7}{1100}-\dfrac{1}{200}\right) =\dfrac{21}{220}-\dfrac{1}{3}=-\dfrac{157}{660}\\
 V_{B}=\dfrac{2200}{3}\cdot \dfrac{-157}{660}=-174.44 [V] \\ V_{B}=V_{th}=-174.44\left[ V\right] \end{gathered} $$

- Final answer for \$ V_{th} \$ doesn't seem to make sense to me, it's too high in comparable to the voltage sources values, and I feel like something along the way didn't work out.

---

***Continuing my Solution***, I solved the circuit to find \$ R_{th} \$, I added a test current source flowing \$ 1 [A] \$ and shorted all the non-dependent voltage sources:
[image]

Solved with node voltage analysis:

$$ \begin{gathered}\left( 1\right)\dfrac{V_{A}}{R_{1}}+\dfrac{V_{A}}{R_{2}}+i_{\Delta }=\dfrac{V_{B}}{R_{5}}+1-10i\Delta-i_{\Delta } \\
\left( 2\right) V_{B}-V_{A} = 0  \Longrightarrow V_{B}=V_{A} \\
\left( 3\right) i_{\Delta}=\dfrac{V_{B}-V_{A}}{R_{3}} = 0 
\end{gathered} $$

Hence,

$$ V_{A} ( \dfrac{1}{330} + \dfrac{1}{300} - \dfrac{1}{200}) = 1 \\
 V_{A} = V_{B} = V_{th} = \dfrac{2200}{3} [V] = 733.33 [V] \\
\Rightarrow R_{th} = \dfrac{V_{th}}{1} = 733.33 [\Omega] $$

Answer also seems incorrect as the load on \$R_{th}\$ which is very big.

To calculate the power I used:

$$ P_{max} = \dfrac{V_{th}^2}{R_{th}} = 41.49 [W] $$

Answer seems very big and I got different answer than most of my class mates.

**- I really don't know why my solution is not working however, I'd appreciate any kind of help!**

Comment: What value for \$R_{th}\$ did you get? Did you get 25 mA for \$I_{\Delta}\$?

Comment: Could you please explain what is \$i_0\$  in eq(1)?

Comment: @Andyaka \$ R_{th} = 733.33[Ω] \$  ( it's in the second part of my solution ) , Yes I got 25 mA for \$I_{\Delta} \$

Comment: @anilberg It should've been \$I_{\Delta} \$ , I fixed it . Thanks for noticing !

Comment: @Losh_EE you have calculated Rth incorrectly; short the voltage sources and open-circuit the current sources and recalculate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem. I know that this approach is not 'smart' but this method will work all the time, even when the circuit is (way) more complicated than this one. Also, this method will check your work.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOitll.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_3+\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3=\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{0-\text{V}_0}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_3=\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

And we also know that \$\text{V}_1-\text{V}_0=\text{V}_\text{a}\$ and \$\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\text{V}_\text{b}\$.

Using \$(2)\$ we can rewrite \$(1)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{0-\text{V}_0}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_0=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}+\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_0=\text{I}_4+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_5}+\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}=\frac{0-\text{V}_0}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\frac{0-\text{V}_0}{\text{R}_1}+\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_0=\frac{1}{\text{n}}\cdot\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}+\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{0-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}=\text{I}_7+\text{I}_8
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can set up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 + I4 == I2 + I3, I0 == I3 + n*I3, I0 == I4 + I5 + I6, 
   I7 == I5 + I6, n*I3 == I7 + I8, I2 == I1 + I8, I1 == (0 - V0)/R1, 
   I2 == V1/R2, I3 == (V1 - V2)/R3, n*I3 == (0 - V3)/R4, I5 == V2/R5, 
   I6 == V2/R6, V1 - V0 == Va, V1 - V2 == Vb}, {I0, I1, I2, I3, I4, 
   I5, I6, I7, I8, V0, V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I0 -> ((1 + n) Vb)/R3, 
  I1 -> (R3 R5 R6 Va + R2 R3 (R5 + R6) (Va - Vb) - n R2 R5 R6 Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  I2 -> (R3 R5 R6 Va + n R1 R5 R6 Vb + R1 R3 (R5 + R6) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), I3 -> Vb/R3, 
  I4 -> (-R2 R3 (R5 + R6) Va + (R2 R3 R5 + R1 (R2 + R3) R5 + 
       R2 (R3 + R5 + n R5) R6 + R1 (R2 + R3 + R5 + n R5) R6) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  I5 -> (R6 (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  I6 -> (R5 (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  I7 -> ((R5 + R6) (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  I8 -> (-R2 R3 (R5 + R6) Va + (R1 + R2) (n R5 R6 + 
       R3 (R5 + R6)) Vb)/(R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)),
   V0 -> (R1 (-R3 R5 R6 Va - R2 R3 (R5 + R6) (Va - Vb) + 
      n R2 R5 R6 Vb))/(R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  V1 -> (R2 R3 R5 R6 Va + R1 R2 (n R5 R6 + R3 (R5 + R6)) Vb)/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  V2 -> (R5 R6 (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
   R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), 
  V3 -> -((n R4 Vb)/R3)}}
```

Now, we can find:

- \$\text{V}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{V}_2\$ and letting \$\text{R}_6\to\infty\$:
  $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\left(\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_\text{b}\right)+\text{R}_1\text{V}_\text{b}\left(\text{n}\text{R}_2-\text{R}_3\right)\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_3\text{R}_5}\tag4$$
- \$\text{I}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding \$\text{I}_6\$ and letting \$\text{R}_6\to0\$:
  $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_\text{b}}{\text{R}_1}-\frac{\text{V}_\text{b}}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{n}\cdot\text{V}_\text{b}}{\text{R}_3}\tag5$$
- \$\text{R}_\text{th}\$ we get by finding:
  $$\text{R}_\text{th}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{th}}{\text{I}_\text{th}}=\frac{\text{R}_1\text{R}_2\text{R}_5}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_5}\tag6$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-codes:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R5 R6 (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
  R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), R6 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=(R5 (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
R2 R3 R5 + R1 R3 (R2 + R5))

In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(R5 (R2 R3 (Va - Vb) + n R1 R2 Vb - R1 R3 Vb))/(
  R3 (R1 R2 R5 + R2 R5 R6 + R1 (R2 + R5) R6)), R6 -> 0]]

Out[3]=(Va - Vb)/R1 - Vb/R2 + (n Vb)/R3

In[4]:=FullSimplify[%2/%3]

Out[4]=(R1 R2 R5)/(R2 R5 + R1 (R2 + R5))
```

So, using your values we get:

- $$\text{V}_\text{th}=\frac{248}{15}\approx16.5333\space\text{V}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_\text{th}=\frac{31}{165}\approx0.187879\space\text{A}\tag8$$
- $$\text{R}_\text{th}=88\space\Omega\tag9$$

Comment: Thank you so much , redid the question and got the same answers !

Comment: @Losh_EE you're welcome, I'm glad that I could help you.